# Reference from PropertyNode invalid when changing referenced cluster

Tags: properties, reference, labview

I created a cluster consisting of four elements which I need to get the variable names from. To do so I added an indicator element to access the the variable names via the `Beschr.Text` (German version of LabVIEW, should be something like `Label.Text`) property provided by a PropertyNode.

[image: LabVIEW sample snippet]

However, when editing the existing cluster (add new variables, expand cluster, change variables, edit variable names etc.) the connections from both `bundle` operator to the cluster indicator element and from the cluster PropertyNode to the `Elem` property node get invalid.

[image: LabVIEW sample snippet with invalid connections]

I assume this is due to editing the cluster since the indicator element for the cluster is not updated after changing the cluster variables which in turn leads to invalid PropertyNodes and invalid references. As a workaround I remove both the indicator element and the cluster PropertyNode, add new ones and redo all needed connections which is quite annoying since I need to implement this snippet several times.

Is there a proper way to update the reference automatically so that I do not need to re-add the invalid elements on the block diagram and redo its connections?

Answer (score 4):

The best way to accomplish what you are trying to do is to use a [typedef](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/lvconcepts/custom_cont_ind_type/#Type_Definitions_and_Strict_Type_Definitions). Basically it allows for use of a control in various places but is only edited in one place. When you bundle your front panel controls, wire the typedef to the top of the bundle node to control the inputs. Now when you create an indicator, it will be linked to the typedef and automatically update whenever the typedef is updated.

[image: This is what it should look like in the block diagram]

Comment: It's even better instead of Bundle, use Bundle By Name - b/c it eliminates possibility to connect something wrong, when cluster data types remain the same, but order will be changed.

Comment: @Dave_St: Thanks for your answer, I am currently working on the implementation. What typedef (instance) did you used for the Cluster input of the bundle operation?

Comment: How did you make this typedef a constant?

Comment: @albert: A typedef can be made from the block diagram or the front panel. Right click the control or constant you wish to change into a typedef and select "Make Type Def." In order to save it, right click it again and select "Open Type Def." A new window will pop up showing your new typedef as a control (this is how you will make changes to it in the future). Close this window and you will be prompted to save.

Comment: I did manage to define a 'normal' typedef (not a strict one) and was able to re-build your screenshot in my VI (assuming same functionality). However, this (at least what I reproduced with your help) does not behave as desired, which might be due to some misunderstandings or unclear description of my problem. How could we further elaborate without getting to chatty in the comments here?

Comment: Perhaps we have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe control refs and property nodes aren't a good solution. What do you hope to accomplish with this piece of code?